# Increase document size in Cloudant

Tags: couchdb, cloudant

I'm storing large amounts of JSON data in Cloudant. I see there is a request limit of 10mb and a document limit of 1mb from the [docs](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/Cloudant/api?topic=cloudant-limits)

I'm needing to raise this limit but have been unsuccessful. I've tried retrieving a `AuthSession` by calling through curl to the `_session` endpoint and using the token to send via

```
curl -X PUT "https://cloudanthost.cloudantnosqldb.appdomain.cloud/_node/_local/_config/couchdb/max_document_size" \
-d "4294967296" \
--cookie "AuthSession=NzNmMTAyNTUtNTFiMy00MmFlLTk1MDItMmFmYmY3NjI5MjFmLWJsdWVtaXg6NUNDQ0RCMDc6rVSibzKdb2l2x0LFSQHhA9YmGc0" \
-H "X-CouchDB-WWW-Authenticate: Cookie" \
-H "Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
```

This returns

```
{
  "error":"forbidden",
  "reason":"server_admin access is required for this request"
}
```

Has anyone has success in increasing these limits or is it blocked?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry - that’s a hard limit that cannot be changed for good reasons. For optimal use of Cloudant, stick to small documents. Needing larger than the limit documents points to a data model issue, or that Cloudant isn’t a good fit for your use case.